# .Net Core Class Library - Exclude Resource Languages

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a class library that references a package that has language resources.

Is it possible to exclude the language resources?

I have tried the following in the class library project file:

This one did stop the language recourses been added, but then anything using the SqlClient on the exe project stopped working

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

This one does not do anything for the class library build. Only works if add to the exe project file that uses the class library. I wanted to avoid that as would need to add it to each exe project that uses the class library

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create `Directory.Build.props` at solution level with the following.

```xml
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en-US</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Directory.Build.props would that only work if both the class library and exe were in the same solution?

Comment: I do not see that a single Directory.Build.prop in one solution would work for another solution from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022).